# Will Stack Exchange switch away from SPDY (fast enough)?

Tags: feature-request, stack-exchange, ssl

There's an old (2.5 years) question asking [Will Stack Exchange support SPDY?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/197001/will-stack-exchange-support-spdy), which was answered with a "not in the foreseeable future".

Fast forward those 2.5 years, and now at least parts of SE network support SPDY/3.1 - at least, SO and Meta.SE do (not Meta.SO, interestingly enough).

However, SPDY/3.1 itself is going away in the *foreseeable future*.

- Google has [set 2016-05-15 as the cutoff date for SPDY support](http://blog.chromium.org/2016/02/transitioning-from-spdy-to-http2.html) in favor of finalized HTTP/2.
  **This date has passed, and Chrome 51 no longer supports SPDY.**
- Nginx already [dropped SPDY support](https://www.nginx.com/blog/nginx-1-9-5/).
- Edge never supported SPDY, opting for HTTP/2 instead.

So, what's the status on replacing SPDY with HTTP/2? CloudFlare, that SE uses to the best of my knowledge, [supports it](https://www.cloudflare.com/http2/).

Any chance that this happens <del>before Chrome cutoff</del> soon?

Comment: Why does it matter? Chrome will just use good old-fashioned HTTP/1.1 after that date, no? It's not like the server-side will suddenly stop responding properly to such requests.

Comment: Correct. The issues are "Chrome will suddenly lose all advantage of newer protocols" and "Get behind the times already".